# How to Design UIViewController Visual Layout Flows like iOS Developer Library

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Which is the tool used to design UI View Controllers and storyboard for iOS NIB UI?

[UPDATE]
I'm looking for a UI Design Tool in terms of layout sketches more than the StoryBoard design of XCode. The aim is to design the flows of the UIViewControllers as depicted by Apple in the iOS Developer Library.

I have checked some layout UML Class diagrams tools like Visual Paradigm, Magic Draw, etc, but they do not have a visual layout for the UI as well.

[image: iOS Developer Library UI Flow Example]

[image: High-level flow interface Example]

Answer (score 2):

UIStoryBoard is the great way to start its easy and fast way to create UI for all ios application

You can start with **studying basic template code** - e.g. tabbar application for your purpose -  File -> New -> Project -> Tabbed application. 

**Navigation:** To navigate from one screen to other screen - you need to embed in navigation controller - Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller/Tab bar Controller

**Connection:** Ctrl + drag to another view controller to push from one scene to other scene..

Navigation can be done via code see [Navigate storyboard via code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443803/storyboard-workflow-for-turn-based-game/21702229#21702229)

Here is an good tutorial for learning storyboards [Tutorial on Storyboard](http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/)

Comment: Thanks, what about designing the sketches only I mean the UI flow only?

Comment: @loretoparisi - you can go for http://proto.io/

Answer (score 1):

You can build all of this very easily in storyboard. Just create a new project and click on "use storyboard". You them drag onto the storyboard the first view and click on "editor" then "embed in tab bar controller". Then click on "embed in navigation controller". To connect views one to another you hold ctrl and drag from one view to another.  This is a fabulous tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: Thanks, my question was more about a tool to create diagrams like Apple used there than the storyboard make itself.

Comment: This is only one way to go for cool wireframing I think http://balsamiq.com/